# How do I use multiple selectors in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to apply a hover effect to a set of images within a div called toolbar:

```
$("#toolbar img").hover(
    function()
    {
        this.src = this.src.replace("_off", "_on");
    },
    function()
    {
        this.src = this.src.replace("_on", "_off");
    }
);
```

But I also want to apply the same effect to a div called tabs without repeating the same code.  cant I do something along these lines:

```
$("#toolbar, #tabs img").hover(
    function()
    {
        this.src = this.src.replace("_off", "_on");
    },
    function()
    {
        this.src = this.src.replace("_on", "_off");
    }
);
```

The problem is the above only applies to the "tabs" div, while the toolbar stops working.  I think I am just getting the jQuery syntax wrong, still sorta new to jQuery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You separate multiple selectors by commas as you did. If you want to recreate the effect as it was in the first example it needs to be:

```
$("#toolbar img, #tabs img")
```

'#toolbar img' is the entire selector. It says "apply this to any img tags that are in a parent element with the id of toolbar". E.g.:

```
<div id ="toolbar">
   <img .../>
   <img .../>
</div>
```

#tabs img, is a whole other selector.

These are the same syntax as CSS selectors, so for more information research that.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$("#toolbar img, #tabs img")`.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't there be "#toolbar img, #tabs" instead of "#toolbar, #tabs img" ?